# How can I share imported CSS file from my microservice through a whole html page?

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, ngx-build-plus

I've created microservice using Angular. I build it in single es2015 module using ngx-build-plus:build.
So, I have a qustion.
How can I import CSS file (`@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'`) in a way to make it possible to share styles from that files between all dom elements.

F.e., I have Dialog component in my microservice which is taken from Angular materials. If I open Dialog, it adds `<div class="cdk-overlay-container"><div>` as the first child of BODY element. So, it's higher of my microservice app.

So, I just want to make it possitble to take and apply styles from that imported file to .cdk-overlay-container. How can I do that?

I was trying to import this CSS file in SCSS of the main component of my microservice, I also was trying to make shadow dom for my app etc. Nothing helps.

Comment: Why not just add the file to the `styles` section of your build in angular.json?

Comment: I was trying to in a such way. But I was importing from node_modules folder and faced with exception when it was impossible to import not from SRC.

I will try to create additional SCSS file, import to that file needed css. After that I will add it to angular.json. just a minute..

Comment: You should be able to import .scss or .css files directly in angular.json from the node_modules directory. I do this all the time with custom builds of Bootstrap and CSS from external libraries. If you're getting exception errors, double-check the paths.

Comment: ah, no. I faced with an exception when I was trying to add an appropriate css to assets. Now it's in styles section and doesn't help me..

Comment: Yes, you are right... it's possible but doesn't help me

"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
            ],

Comment: If it's in the styles section, the styles are available across your entire application. Remember, each Angular component provides encapsulation for it's styles. If you want to turn that off, you need to set: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `@Component` declaration

Comment: Do I need to do that for the top component, yes?

Comment: You need that for each and every component that you don't want encapsulated styling on.